# Kotlin returns same object from Factory method

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm playing with Kotlin and found interesting behavior.
So lets say i want to have some kind of a Factory :

```
internal interface SomeStupidInterface {
    companion object FACTORY {
       fun createNew(): ChangeListener {
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            return ChangeListener { element -> Log.e("J2KO", "time " + time) }
        }

        fun createTheSame(): ChangeListener {
            return ChangeListener { element -> Log.e("J2KO", "time " + System.currentTimeMillis()) }
        }
    }

    fun notifyChanged()
}
```

where `ChangeListener` defined in java file:

```
interface ChangeListener {
    void notifyChange(Object element);
}
```

And then I try to use it from Java like so:

```
ChangeListener a = SomeStupidInterface.FACTORY.createNew();
ChangeListener b = SomeStupidInterface.FACTORY.createNew();
ChangeListener c = SomeStupidInterface.FACTORY.createTheSame();
ChangeListener d = SomeStupidInterface.FACTORY.createTheSame();
Log.e("J2KO", "createNew a == b -> " + (a == b));
Log.e("J2KO", "createTheSame c == d -> " + (c == d));
```

The results are:

```
createNew: a == b -> false
createTheSame: c == d -> true
```

I can understand why `createNew` returns new objects due to closure. 
But why I'm receiving the same instance from `createTheSame` method?

P.S. I know that code above is not idiomatic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note: your example code doesn't work as is: the interface has to be written in Java in order to be available for use with SAM constructors.

As for the actual question, you've already touched on why this behavior is happening. Lambdas (in this case, the SAM constructors) are compiled to anonymous classes (unless they're inlined). If they capture any outside variables, then for every invocation, a new instance of the anonymous class will be created. Otherwise, since they don't have to have any state, only a single instance will back every invocation of the lambda. I suppose this is for performance reasons, if nothing else. (Credit to the [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action) book for the information in this paragraph.)

If you want to return a new instance every time without capturing any variables, you can use the full `object` notation:

```
fun createNotQUiteTheSame(): ChangeListener {
    return object : ChangeListener {
        override fun notifyChanged(element: Any?) {
            println("time " + System.currentTimeMillis())
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the above function multiple times will return different instances for each call. Interestingly, IntelliJ will suggest converting this to the original SAM conversion syntax instead:

```
fun createNotQUiteTheSame(): ChangeListener {
    return ChangeListener { println("time " + System.currentTimeMillis()) }
}
```

Which, as you've already found out, returns the same instance every time.

I suppose this conversion is offered because comparing whether these stateless instances are equal is very much an edge case. If you need to be able to do comparison between the instances that are returned, you're probably best off with the full `object` notation. Then you can even add some additional state to each listener, in the form of an `id` for example.

Comment: Good catch - I've moved callback from java to Kotlin without a check. Going to update my question with original code. 
And you are right - I was fooled by AS suggestion. When I use full object notation all works as expected

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with performance. Creating less objects obviously is better for performance, so that is what Kotlin tries to do.

For each lambda, Kotlin generates a class that implements the proper interface. So for example the following Kotlin code:

```
fun create() : () -> Unit {
  return { println("Hello, World!") }
}
```

corresponds with something like:

```
Function0 create() {
  return create$1.INSTANCE;
}

final class create$1 implements Function0 {

  static final create$1 INSTANCE = new create$1();

  void invoke() {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```

You can see here that the same instance is always returned.

---

If you reference a variable that is outside of the lamdba scope however, this won't work: there is no way for the singleton instance to access that variable.

```
fun create(text: String) : () -> Unit {
  return { println(text) }
}
```

Instead, for each invocation of `create`, a new instance of the class needs to be instantiated which has access to the `text` variable:

```
Function0 create(String text) {
  return new create$1(text);
}

final class create$1 implements Function0 {

  final String text;

  create$1(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  void invoke() {
    System.out.println(text);
  }
}
```

That is why your `a` and `b` instances are the same, but `c` and `d` are not.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks for explenation

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you try to use [SAM conversion](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) with Kotlin interface.

Note that SAM conversions only work for interfaces, not for abstract classes, even if those also have just a single abstract method.

Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

For implementing interface like you want, you need to use object expression.
Also look at [high order functions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions) - I think you need them for your solution.

```
internal interface SomeStupidInterface {
    interface ChangeListener {
        fun notifyChanged(element: Any)
    }

    companion object FACTORY {
        fun createNew(): ChangeListener {
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            return object : ChangeListener {
                override fun notifyChanged(element: Any) {
                    println("J2KO" + "time " + time)
                }
            }
        }

        fun createTheSame(): ChangeListener {
            return object : ChangeListener {
                override fun notifyChanged(element: Any) {
                    println("J2KO" + "time " + System.currentTimeMillis())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun notifyChanged()
}
```

Also In IntelliJ IDEA I can't compile your code.